# How to get the number of deaths per month in this dataset?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, interpolation, mortality

This dataset shows the number of deaths (of all causes) in the US in 2019.  It's labeled in weeks.  What is the right interpretation of this for getting the number of deaths in January?  Should I add the E-column up until 2019-01-26?  I know I'd miss the last few days of the month, but am I getting the number of deaths in the first 4 weeks of 2019?  (Or am I reading this completely wrong?)

[image: Deaths in January 2019]

If you think this is correct, consider the month of June 2019.  The sum of these numbers either add up to roughly 210,000 or to 260,000, which is a lot.  But I guess that's just it --- there doesn't seem to be any other possible interpretation here.

[image: June 2019]

[Original source](https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/muzy-jte6/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD&bom=true&format=true&delimiter=%3B).

Comment: You could use $\frac57$ of the first row, all of the next three and $\frac57$ of the fifth row as a reasonable estimate for January.  Remember that February will have fewer days

Comment: That's cool info, thanks.  But my concern is just that these numbers don't appear correct.  For instance, if I add this column for the month of June 2019, I roughly get 210,000 or 260,000, which seems like a lot compared to previous years.  I know the question seems obvious, but have to ask and I think you are reading it in the same way I am.

Comment: The same approach to June would be $\frac17$ of MMWR week 22, the four rows you highlighted, and $\frac17$ of week 27.  But I would have thought weeks were a better basis of analysis

Comment: That's true, but I have monthly data for the previous years and weekly data for 2019 and 2020.  Anyway, your idea of distributing the deaths by the linear proportion of the days of each month in that week seems to be the best idea.  That is actually the answer to the question that I didn't ask.  Sometimes the real answer is a better question.  Thank you for that.  Your comments answer the real question.

Comment: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/excess-mortality-raw-death-count?tab=chart&stackMode=absolute&country=~USA&region=World has a chart of total USA deaths by week back to 2015, though remember that the USA has a growing elderly population so you would expect the numbers to be rising on average each year by a small amount

Comment: That's great insight!  This could explain why some countries have a much lower mortality.  Perhaps they have much younger population.